# Configuring Yaboot and Debian to Boot into a Command Line Login Shell?

Tags: shell, debian, command-line, powerpc, runlevel

I have a Debian Squeeze variant (MintPPC 9) installed on an old Mac Powerbook G4 (PowerPC CPU). I wish to boot it into a multiuser CLI login shell instead of automatically booting into the login screen for LXDE. I do, however, wish to keep GDM or whatever DM is used by LXDE since I also use it to switch between LXDE and Awesome WM.

I wish to boot by default into a CLI login shell; I could then `startx` to start my GUI if I need it. I am aware that `Ctrl-Alt-(F1-6)` will open a separate tty instance with a login shell but it seems wasteful to have a GUI running even if asleep if I am working purely from the command line particularly considering the limited resources of my Powerbook G4.

I now know how to do this on Ubuntu installs on other, Intel based machines, by configuring GRUB, however this machine uses Yaboot as the bootloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra options in grub on the `kernel` line are in fact [kernel boot options](http://oreilly.com/linux/excerpts/9780596100797/kernel-boot-command-line-parameter-reference.html) passed across to the kernel when loaded.

So if you are referring to appending `text` to the grub line in [Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=843646), then the same config should be able to be [used for mint](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=44671&p=257103&hilit=startx#p257103) and passed to the kernel by Yaboot.

[It looks like](http://mac.linux.be/content/yaboot) Yaboot supports an `append=` option

```
append="root=/dev/sda4 ro quiet splash text"
```